# Позиционирование в файле

Tags: c++, c, алгоритм, файлы

В коде есть две подпрограммы: `а` и `b`. Каждая подпрограмма должна работать с одним и тем же файлом. Соответственно, в зависимости от вызванной функции должно меняться позиционирование в файле. Как это правильно сделать? Подойдет ли здесь функция `fseek`? Можно ли менять позиционирование прямо по строкам?

Вот код:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#define _CRT_NONSTDC_NO_WARNINGS

#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <locale>
#include <string.h>

FILE* fOpenForReadSavely(const char* filename) {//открывает файл для чтения, если он есть, или создает новый
    FILE *file;
    file = fopen(filename, "r");
    if (file == NULL) {
        fclose(file);
        file = fopen(filename, "w");
        fclose(file);
        file = fopen(filename, "r");
    }
    return file;
}
FILE* fOpenForWriteSavely(const char* filename) {//открывает файл для записи, если он есть, или создает новый
    FILE *file;
    file = fopen(filename, "r+");
    if (file == NULL) {
        fclose(file);
        file = fopen(filename, "w");
        fclose(file);
        file = fopen(filename, "r+");
    }
    return file;
}

void printMin() {
    FILE *file = fOpenForReadSavely("io.txt");
    char buffer[100];

    fseek(file, 8, SEEK_END);
    fgets(buffer, 100, file);
    //printf("\nmin = %d", min);
    puts(buffer);

    fclose(file);
}
void printm() {
    char buffer[100];
    FILE *file = fOpenForReadSavely("io.txt");
    fgets(buffer, 100, file);
    puts(buffer);
    fclose(file);
}
void findMin() {
    FILE *file = fOpenForReadSavely("io.txt");
    int min = INT32_MAX;
    int m[20];
    char buffer[100],*element;

    fseek(file, 0, SEEK_SET);
    fgets(buffer, 100, file);
    element = strtok(buffer, " ");

    for (int i = 1; i < 20; i++) {
        m[i] = (int)element;
        element = strtok(NULL, " ");
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        if (m[i] < min && m[i]) min = m[i];
    }
    fseek(file, 0, SEEK_END);
    fprintf(file, "\n min = %2d", min);

    fclose(file);
}
void generateM(int m[], char *filename) {
    srand(time(NULL));
    FILE *file = fOpenForWriteSavely(filename);

    fseek(file, 0, SEEK_SET);

    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        m[i] = rand() % 32;
        fprintf(file, "%2d ", m[i]);
    }
    //fprintf(file, "\n");

    fclose(file);
}
void printmm() {
    FILE *file = fOpenForReadSavely("io.txt");

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
            //printf("%2d ", m[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    fclose(file);
}
void printNearEquals() {
    FILE *file = fOpenForReadSavely("io.txt");

    //printf("count = %d", count);

    fclose(file);
}
void findNearEquals() {
    FILE *file = fOpenForReadSavely("io.txt");

    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
            //if (m[i][j] == m[i][j + 1]) count++;
        }
    }

    fclose(file);
}
void generateMM(int **m) {
    FILE *file = fOpenForWriteSavely("io.txt");

    srand(time(NULL));
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
            m[i][j] = rand() % 32;
        }
    }

    fclose(file);
}
char* getFileName() {
    char * filename;
    scanf("%s", &filename);
    if (strstr(filename, ".txt") == NULL) {
        strcat(".txt", filename);
    }
    return filename;
}

void a() {
    int m[20];
    int* p = m;
    char *filename;

    printf("Введите имя файла: ");
    filename = getFileName();

    generateM(p, filename);
    printm();
    findMin();
    printMin();

}
void b() {
    int** m;
    m = new int*[10];
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        m[i] = new int[10];

    generateMM(m);
    printmm();
    findNearEquals();
    printNearEquals();

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        delete[] m[i];
    delete[] m;
}

int main() {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
    printf("Задание а или б: ");
    char c = getchar();
    if (c == 'a' | c == 'а') {
        a();
    }
    else if (c == 'b' | c == 'б') {
        b();
    }
    else if (c != 'a' | c != 'b' | c != 'а' | c != 'б') {
        printf("\nerror");
        getch();
    }
    getch();
}
```

Comment: Возможности позиционирования сильно отличаются для бинарных и для текстовых файлов. Вы открываете файлы в текстовом режиме. В текстовых файлах произвольного позиционирования нет вообще, кроме возможности сделать `fseek` на позицию, ранее возвращенную `ftell`.

Answer (score 3):

Про позиционирование в текстовых файлах вам уже написали в комментарии - [@AnT](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/182825/ant). Впрочем, ваши вызовы `fseek` выставляют позицию в файле только на начало или конец, и тут все будет работать нормально (в смысле - выставлять указатель, куда надо, потому как у MS [сказано](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/75yw9bf3.aspx): *корректно работает поиск со смещением 0 относительно любого значения origin*). Кроме одного вызова - о нем далее:

```
fseek(file, 8, SEEK_END);
```

Здесь вы пытаетесь выйти за пределы файла - на 8 байт дальше, чем он заканчивается. Это в принципе не запрещено (см. [там же](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/75yw9bf3.aspx)), но пустые места забьются нулями. Это точно желательное для вас поведение?

```
if (file == NULL) {
    fclose(file);
```

Не стоит закрывать *не открытый* файл. Вот что сказано в [документации](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/fxfsw25t.aspx):

*Функция fclose закрывает stream.  Если параметр stream имеет значение NULL, вызывается обработчик недопустимого параметра, как описано в разделе Проверка параметров.  Если выполнение может быть продолжено, то fclose устанавливает errno в EINVAL и возвращает EOF.  Рекомендуется, всегда проверять указатель stream до вызова этой функции.*

```
    file = fopen(filename, "w");
    fclose(file);
    file = fopen(filename, "r");
```

Здесь вы создаете пустой файл и открываете его для чтения. Что же из него можно будет прочесть?

```
    file = fopen(filename, "w");
    fclose(file);
    file = fopen(filename, "r+");
```

Здесь создается пустой файл, затем открывается для записи и чтения. Но это же можно выразить одним вызовом -

```
    file = fopen(filename, "w+");
```

(см. [тут](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/yeby3zcb.aspx)).